# How do I query multiple images from an array with gatsby-image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have a collection of works that are available through a Strapi API endpoint. Each work has an array containing multiple images. I would like to render them using gatsby-image but I don't have any idea how to do it since all available examples on docs are made with single files or static files on the "images" folder.

When trying the GraphiQL explorer I realized the thumbnail image has this value on 'id' key:

```
"thumbnail": {
          "id": "e:/wamp/www/@flaex_/app/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/52e3542d00600c96e52cb584e83c2cae.jpg absPath of file"}
```

Meaning that the image had been registered on gatsby cache. On the other side the 'id' key on each image of the array show this:

```
"images": [
          {
            "id": "5d0d7429fe6de132d43a44b4",
            "url": "/uploads/01d8a893fe4c46738b1c99624d22154d.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": "5d0d7429fe6de132d43a44b3",
            "url": "/uploads/eb399dfadea74b9db39672a1f98575ff.jpg"
          }
        ]
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

This is the template I'm using:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import containerStyles from "../pages/portfolio.module.less"

const WorkTemplate = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <div className={containerStyles.navsec}>
      <button onClick={() => window.history.back()}>&#60;&#60; back</button>
    </div>
    <article>
      <h1>{data.strapiWork.title}</h1>      
      <Img fluid={data.strapiWork.thumbnail.childImageSharp.fluid} />
      <p>{data.strapiWork.description}</p>
      {console.log(data.strapiWork.images)}      
      <ul className={containerStyles.works}>
          {data.allStrapiWork.images.map(document => (
            <li key={document.id}>              
               <Img fluid={document.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />

            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>       
    </article>
  </Layout>
)

export default WorkTemplate

export const query = graphql`
  query WorkTemplate($id: String!) {
    strapiWork(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      title
      description
      images {        
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 120) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }       
      }
      thumbnail {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 500) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }      
    }
  }
`
```

I presume this is not working because 'images' is an array.

The thumbnail image is rendering fine, as it can be seen I tried to replicate the graphQL query used on the thumbnail image but I'm getting this message on the console when running `gatsby develop`:

error GraphQL Error Encountered 1 error(s):                                                                             - Unknown field 'childImageSharp' on type '[StrapiWorkImages]'.

I would appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the error message and the return from the explorer...have you tried `<Img fluid={document.fluid}/>`

Comment: I tried what you suggested. When I run gastby develop this is the error I'm getting:

`
e:\wamp\www\@flaex_\app\src\templates\work.js                                                                             38:9  error  Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiWorkImages"  graphql/template-strings                
✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)      

`

This is the line that is causing the error:

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a3qah2vq0tpxmn/Annotation%202019-07-06%20132047.png?dl=0)

Comment: In the Graphql playground what is the schema for the image on strapi? Can you log out the `data` so we can see the structure that is returned?

Comment: `childImageSharp` is the issue here but I don't know what structure is returned by `StrapiWorkImages`

Comment: I am also assuming you have installed and configured the `gatsby-image` plugin?

Comment: Yes, gatsby-image is properly installed and configured, I'm having no problems rendering single images (post images, works thumbnails). I'm stuck on how to render an array of images from the Strapi's endpoint.
This is the data object logged out on console, the blue dot is the thumbnail that I'm rendering without problems, the orange dot is the array of images I'm stuck with
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zaxnct9jc0wcso/Annotation%202019-07-08%20102037.png?dl=0)

Comment: Ah ok so if you look at what is being returned on the images array as opposed to your thumbnails, it is just a simple array of urls....try rendering them out not using gatsby image (i.e just a normal `<img src="document"/>` . also in your query take out the `ChildImageSharp` . `GraphiQL` should give you a good idea of what you can use also....

Comment: I tried rendering the images without gatsby-images before and I ended writing manually the url since they were created on Strapi. I was first against this solution because I thought it would be a kind of pain when going to deploy the production version and that it would be nice to use the features of the gatsby-image component to optimize image processing.
This is the component rendering the array images [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v58ts1jpuwq8owz/code-1.png?dl=0)
This is the query I'm using [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpzd9kcocgoqhcw/code-2.png?dl=0)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Gatsby repo (on the `gatsby-source-strapi` plugin) and it seems like it is an open issue at the moment. So it is not something you are doing wrong at all. Not sure if this will help at all? I think for some it hasn't.
[Image workaround](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues)

Comment: I think the link is missing.

Comment: To be more specific, the solution to this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues/45)